# How to dispatch async actions in react only once?

Tags: reactjs

How to dispatch async actions in react only once?

I'm using react functional components.

I'm using react-redux with redux-thunk for performing side effects(along with reselect).

Following is a component that dispatches an async action and select the items from the store.

```
const Card = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch(Effects.getItems());
  const items = useSelector(selectitems);

  return (
    <Container>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <p>{item.name}</p>
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

The problem is that this is sending network requests infinitely and my browser is getting crashed.

I'm receiving back the data. But the problem is that it is sending infinite requests in the behind.

How can I solve this? i.e. to only fetch data once.

Do I need to wrap this inside any hooks? What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: put the dispach call in `useEffect(>dispatch here<, [dispatch])`, or if you need call it only once per app life time add flag in your store that indicates if items were fetched and check if it before calling dispatch

Answer (score 1):

You need to use useEffect with empty array dependencies. So it will call only once time:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(Effects.getItems());
}, [])
```